# exFAT read-only after crash

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit

After system crash my USB stick with exFAT gets read-only.
To revert it back to read-write I have to format it every time this happens.
I would rather have fixed it without formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing a filesystem error check on it?  I bet if you do this then it will become read-write again.  This is probably a safety mechanism to protect you from corrupting a volume that wasn't cleanly closed.

Comment: Yep. Running chkdsk makes it read-write again. Funny thing is chkdsk shows there were no errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different USB "stick" and see if you can replicate the behavior? You might have a faulty (or failing one).

Comment: It doesn't fail itself without a reason. It gets corrupted only after system crashes.